# Issues with email host and SmtpClient

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, smtpclient

I have an asp.net application on framework 4.6.1 that sends emails (status updates and the like). It sends emails fine from several users emails (we have their credentials stored) hosted on Google, Comcast, ATT, etc but one host (hostgator) is giving us problems. The email addresses are through the user's domain with hostgator. (Essentially, the business is trying to migrate their users from their personal emails to company emails.)

Emails will send to other users within the email's domain, but won't send outside of the domain and the email host isn't sure what's happening. The host is asking if the application uses Secure Password Authentication and for the life of me I can't find any reference to that in the literature I am reading.

Anyone have any ideas on what we can do? Below is a snippet of the code I have in place that is otherwise working.

```
    Dim client As New SmtpClient

    client.Host = smtpClientString
    client.EnableSsl = True
    client.Port = smtpPortInteger
    client.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(fromEmailString, emailPasswordString)

    Try

        client.Send(message)
        Return "Success"

    Catch ex As Exception

        Return ex.Message

    End Try
```

Comment: I presume it's something hostgator is blocking internally suspecting like a spambot or whatever. But their staff have been unable to confirm anything.

Comment: Why does your application need to send a message *as that user*? That introduces issues like the one you ran into, but also now you have to find a way to securely store those credentials. Instead, have you considered sending an email from a service account like "noreply@mycompany.com" on behalf of the user?

Comment: It's because each of the users is a sales person and it is a way to send their quotes and what not directly from their account. Originally it did come from one account but they decided they wanted it more personal and have an easier time to manage replys (when I had a different reply to email from the sender it very commonly was flagged as spam by the recipient)

Comment: hostgator said they are blocking the messages because the HELO is the server's name and they need to see something else there for it not to be caught by their spam filters. Can I specify that in the SMTPClient?